# How to display the count in datagridview using windows forms

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my application i am displaying the messages if file is uploaded successfully and at the same time i am displaying the message that it is not uploaded in a message box.

The problem is i need to click ok button in message box each and every time when the message occours. Suppose if 40 files are not inserted i need to click ok button for 40 times. I need to display the files which are inserted and which are not inserted at a time in a datagridview. how can i do this.

```
if (ErrorMessage == 0)
{
    Ffname += path + "-" + "Uploaded successfully" + "\n";
}
else
{
     NotInsFiles += path + " - " + "Not Inserted" + "\n";
}
lbluplodedfile.Text = TabNotIns;
if (Ffname != null || Ffname != "")
{
    MessageBox.Show(Ffname);
    lbluplodedfile.Text = Ffname;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(NotInsFiles);
}
```

Comment: what does the click button do? cant you put it in a timer?

Comment: it is not the click button it is the button that we get in message box that is normal ok button

Comment: Well yes because the messagebox.show will halt the code until you respond to it....

Comment: yes i need to bind them finally in datagridview instead of displaying in message box suppose if i upload 40 files and in that 15 are inserted and 25 are not inserted i need to display them in datagridview with two columns as inserted and not inserted and in inserted i need to show those 15 files and in not inserted i need to show 25 files that too at last

Comment: It seems you are looking for a way to log the actions your program has taken, why not create a list containing those messages, or a textbox to which you add those messages? Also, is the code you are showing here part of a foor loop?

Comment: no it is not a part of for loop but it is after for loop could you help me out in doing this

Comment: i need to show the uploaded and not uploaded files in datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do loop around your upload file and you have to adding in this loop the

```
if (ErrorMessage == 0)
{
    Ffname += path + "-" + "Uploaded successfully" + "\n";
}
else
{
     NotInsFiles += path + " - " + "Not Inserted" + "\n";
}
```

and when the loop finish try to show message box

To display image in datagridview you have to insert column of type DataGridViewImageColumn and after you can display image inside.

```
        private void ImgToDataGridView()
        {
            /* List of path of img */
            List<string> pathImgUpload = new List<string>();
            List<string> pathNotInsert = new List<string>();

            /* Just for my test */
            pathImgUpload.Add("./abc.png");
            pathImgUpload.Add("./abc.png");
            pathImgUpload.Add("./abc.png");
            pathImgUpload.Add("./abc.png");

            pathNotInsert.Add("./abc.png");
            pathNotInsert.Add("./abc.png");
            pathNotInsert.Add("./abc.png");
            pathNotInsert.Add("./abc.png");
            pathNotInsert.Add("./abc.png");

            /* Creation of columns for the good and bad img */
            DataGridViewImageColumn colImgUpload = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            DataGridViewImageColumn colImgNotInsert = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colImgUpload);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colImgNotInsert);

            /* Max of size of pathImgUpload and pathNotInsert */
            var lineadd = pathImgUpload.Count > pathNotInsert.Count ? pathImgUpload.Count : pathNotInsert.Count;

            /* Create the good number of line (-1 because a first line is already in datagridview)*/
            for(int i = 0; i <lineadd - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            /* adding good img */
            for (int i = 0; i < pathImgUpload.Count(); i++)
            {
                string path = pathImgUpload[i];
                var img = new Bitmap(path);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = img;
            }

            /* adding bad img */
            for(int i = 0; i < pathNotInsert.Count();i++)
            {
                string path = pathNotInsert[i];
                var img = new Bitmap(path);
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = img;
            }
        }
```

Comment: i need to show the uploaded and not uploaded files in datagridview

Comment: look this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784440/how-display-images-in-datagridview-c-sharp