# How to bind image in datagridview windows forms from local project folder

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am creating a windows form application. I want to display image from local folder in my datagridview for `Active` from my datatable.

If Active is `yes` then i want to display `yes` image from image folder and active is no then I want to display `No` image from local  image folder.

```
private void getAll()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));           
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(bool));
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", true);
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Avil", false );
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", false);
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", false);
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", false);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    //dataGridView1.datab
}
```

I have already view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784440/how-display-images-in-datagridview-c-sharp) but this is not as my question.

Comment: @ArunPratap are you really sure this is duplicate of above question

Comment: @ArunPratap i already view this answer before post my qustion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated getAll() function. You can add condition while setting image in the data table row.

```
    private void getAll()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Active", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("ActiveStatus", typeof(Image));


        String yesPath = @"C:\temp\Yes.png";
        String noPath = @"C:\temp\No.png";

        // Here we add five DataRows. You can add condition here to set appropriate image path.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", true,Image.FromFile(yesPath));
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Avil", false, Image.FromFile(noPath));
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", false, Image.FromFile(noPath));
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", false, Image.FromFile(noPath));
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", false, Image.FromFile(noPath));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```