# Error when loading a data grid that I supposedly updated an image to?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

This is my first time using this website, sorry if I break any rules.

So my database consists of 1 table, Student. It has a PK of ID, then its other attributes are Name, Email and Image(of type image).
I already added 4 records but without the image as I didn't have it in mind when originally making the table. I have a function that allows me to update and another to add an image. The way it works is that we choose a file which will then be displayed to a picturebox. Then convert the image in the picturebox to bytes.

My teacher won't teach us how to load images so I'm relying on this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIv1_P98Ne8&ab_channel=BasselTech)

Heres some of the code

```cs
//Adding an entirely new record
var sid = Int32.Parse(textID.Text);
string NAME = textName.Text;
string EMAIL = textEmail.Text;
var IMAGE = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(Byte[]));

if (sid == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(NAME) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(EMAIL))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Information in all the boxes");
}
else
{
    string query = "Insert into Student values('" + sid + "', '" + NAME + "', '" + EMAIL + "', '"+IMAGE+"')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
    display();
}

//updating an old record
string NAME = textName.Text;
string EMAIL = textEmail.Text;
var sid = Int32.Parse(textID.Text);
var IMAGE = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(pictureBox1.Image, typeof(Byte[]));

if (sid == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Choose the ID of the Student you want to change");
}
else{
    int count = 0;
    string query = "Update Student Set ";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NAME))
        count++;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EMAIL))
        count++;
    if(IMAGE != null)
        count++;
    //counts finished

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NAME) && count == 1)
        query = query + "Name = '"+Name+"' ";
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(NAME) && count >1)
        query = query = query + "Name = '"+Name+"' , ";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EMAIL) && count >=1 && count < 3)
        query = query + "Email = '"+EMAIL+"' ";
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EMAIL) && count == 3)
        query = query = query + "Email = '"+EMAIL+"' , ";

    if(IMAGE != null)
        query = query + "Image = '"+IMAGE+"' ";

    query = query + "where ID = '" + sid + "' ";

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    con.Close();
    display();
}
```

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT7Jd.png)

edit: code for Load Image button for pictureBox:

```cs
OpenFileDialog OD = new OpenFileDialog();
OD.FileName = "";
OD.Filter = "Supported Images|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png";
if (OD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if user presses ok
    pictureBox1.Load(OD.FileName);
```

Comment: The Error comes from the DataGridView. It must have a [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784563/880990) to display the image. When does the error occur exactly? Where is the code that loads the image into the dgv? Is the dgv bound to an object or to a DataTable?

Comment: Your image bytes are treated as a string. Both Insert and Update queries must be rebuilt correctly, all using Parameters. Don't concatenate strings to build a query. Ever. -- `var IMAGE` is misleading.

Comment: @Jimi Can you give me an example of how to use Parameters? Do I create 2 Sql commands (1 for image 1 for the rest)?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The error occurs after uploading the image.  The dgv is bound to a DataTable which has an a column for image already

Comment: See e.g.: [How to Store and Read Byte Array in SQL Server Database using C# .Net](https://morgantechspace.com/2014/05/how-to-store-and-read-byte-array-in-sql-server-using-csharp.html). Of course you would also specify sid, name and email as command parameters. This is much safer and  frees you from the task of worrying about string delimiters appearing within the string, about number and date formats etc.